# Trying to switch data using a Tab bar, but only the first tab is working and getting empty response on the second tab

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am switching the data using a tab bar, but it's working for only the first tab.

```
TabBarView(controller: _tabController, children: [
                  PostGridScreen(type: "Bread", city: city, state: state),
                  PostGridScreen(type: "Cookie", city: city, state: city),
                  PostGridScreen(type: "Cake", city: city, state: city),
                ])
```

This is how I am fetching the data

```
class PostGridScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String type, city, state;
  PostGridScreen({this.type, this.city, this.state});

  @override
  _PostGridScreenState createState() => _PostGridScreenState();
}

class _PostGridScreenState extends State<PostGridScreen>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  List<DocumentSnapshot> products = [];
  bool isLoading = false;
  bool hasMore = true;
  int documentLimit = 6;
  DocumentSnapshot lastDocument;
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    getPosts();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      double maxScroll = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
      double currentScroll = _scrollController.position.pixels;
      double delta = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.20;
      if (maxScroll - currentScroll <= delta) {
        getPosts();
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  getPosts() async {
    if (!hasMore) {
      print('No More Products');
      return;
    }
    if (isLoading) {
      return;
    }
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> response;
    if (lastDocument == null) {
      response = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("posts")
          .where('type', isEqualTo: widget.type)
          .where('sellercity', isEqualTo: widget.city)
          .where('sellerstate', isEqualTo: widget.state)
          .limit(documentLimit)
          .get();
    } else {
      response = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("posts")
          .where('type', isEqualTo: widget.type)
          .where('sellercity', isEqualTo: widget.city)
          .where('sellerstate', isEqualTo: widget.state)
          .startAfterDocument(lastDocument)
          .limit(documentLimit)
          .get();
    }
    if (response.docs.length < documentLimit) {
      hasMore = false;
    }
    lastDocument = response.docs[response.docs.length - 1];
    products.addAll(response.docs);
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

This is how I am showing it

```
ListView.builder(
        controller: _scrollController,
        key: PageStorageKey('Page1'),
        itemCount: products.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index)
```

The error I am receiving

```
E/flutter (18484): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: -1
E/flutter (18484): #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:254:60)
E/flutter (18484): #1      _PostGridScreenState.getPosts
package:softclaw/…/search/postgridscreen.dart:78
E/flutter (18484): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18484):
```

I think there is something wrong with how i am fetching the data. May be the list is staying as same as the first page and showing error or the snapshot. I don't know what exactly I am doing wrong here. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `response.docs.length` is actually return `0` since you `response.docs` is coming out to be empty.

That is why when you trying `lastDocument = response.docs[response.docs.length - 1]` you are trying to access `response.docs[-1]` and that's why the error says `-1` at the end.

You should check why your query is returning empty list.

Also, have an `if` check before accessing.

```
if (response.docs != null and response.docs.isNotEmpty) {
  lastDocument = response.docs[response.docs.length - 1];
  // Any other code depending on docs should go here
}
```

Also, at the top, you have used,

```
PostGridScreen(type: "Cookie", city: city, state: city),
PostGridScreen(type: "Cake", city: city, state: city),
```

Where as, it should be `state: state`, which is probably causing the lack of data in above case.

Comment: Thanks Nisanth, now I am getting no error on when switching to second tab, but still man products are loading only for the first screen. Do you know what should i do or where should i look?

Comment: Hi, you have used it like this at the top `PostGridScreen(type: "Cookie", city: city, state: city),`. Shouldnt it be `state: state` ?

Comment: OHHH MY GOD, that was it; Thank you Nishant Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I didn't know how to send data between Tabs in Tabbar. finally I used global variables.